# Load XIB this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, xib

I just create custom `UIView` with name `PopupViewForViewMoreDetail` and I want to add this custom view in my *ViewController* but each time getting below error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<0x7f8155f2e430> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mainView.'

if I remove **IBOutlet**  of **mainView** then It will be display error for another variable.

Below is my code

```
import UIKit

class PopupViewForViewMoreDetail: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var darkBGView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var outerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var mainView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var btnClose: UIButton!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

and I'm adding this view in my viewController class like below.

```
 let viewMoreDetailPopUp =  Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PopupViewForViewMoreDetail", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! PopupViewForViewMoreDetail
        self.view.addSubview(viewMoreDetailPopUp)
```

Below is my screenshot for **IBOutlets**

[image]

I also checked below answer but didn't help me.

[What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: … this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v)

Guide me where I'm going wrong in my code ?

Comment: Change `owner: self` to `owner: nil`

Comment: I changed but not working

Answer (score 56, accepted):

try this :

> step 1:

```
let viewMoreDetailPopUp =  UINib(nibName: "PopupViewForViewMoreDetail", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! PopupViewForViewMoreDetail
```

> step 2:
>   make sure you're setting class for the view instead of File's Owner[image]

[image]

> Step 3 :
>   Remove all outlets and re-outlet again

Comment: Connecting the outlet to the view, and not the file owner, was the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @TungVuDuc can you explain *why* setting the view's class rather than the file's owner's one is required here?

Comment: @Johnson_145 because when you creating a `view` from nib, their subviews belong to its `view` not file's owner

Comment: Thank you. save my time.

Comment: This is the only solution that works! Beware: After doing the things @TungVuDuc described and still get the same error, check the outlets pointing from the File's Owner. You may need to remove them in case you created them while trying to get this to work!

Comment: @Crashalot Exactly! remove all outlets and remove class from "File's Owner". Then  add class for "view". Without removing previous outlets or both selected class create same issue also.

Comment: Setting the class for view instead of File Owner means the view outlet must be removed, and then I get this error:  `loaded the "CustomNibName" nib but the view outlet was not set.'`

Comment: Thanks saved a lot of time, I was trying to use file owner however not a chance.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was that I copied a xib to make a new variation and it unchecked inherit module from target.