# Swift load UIViewController from xib IBOutlets nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xib

I'm pulling out what little hair I have left!

I have a UIViewController with a matching .xib file.  In the .xib, I have an IBOutlet that I made in interface builder called "titleText"

In a section of my code, I have the following lines:

```
let fooVC = FooViewController(nibName: "FooViewController", bundle: Bundle.main)
fooVC.titleText = "TEST"
```

The viewController "seems" to load fine, I get an object of the correct type, but the IBOutlets are not initialized.

Is there an additional step that I need to do to initialize any IBOutlets that I may have?

This has got to be something really simple, right?!

Comment: Check out [this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321383/iboutlet-is-nil-but-it-is-connected-in-storyboard-swift).

Comment: make sure your outlets are connected

Comment: Outlets are available only after `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Check out my solution here, it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/51056443/7561768

Comment: I tried looking at the solutions mentioned, they did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlets are nil until the view loads. So just make another variable and store title string like below

```
class FooViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet titleText:UILable!
    var titleString:String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       titleText.text = titleString
    }
}
```

**Use:**

```
let fooVC = FooViewController()
fooVC.titleString = "TEST"
```

Comment: No , loadViewIfNeeded will make it load

Comment: The fix that actually worked for me was

`_  = self.view` in the `viewDidLoad()` method