# Custom headerView for tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to make a custom headerView for my tableview. I have followed many guides but can't resolve one problem.

1. I used to subclass UITableViewHeaderFooterView and created xib file.

[image]

Added view (to be a container view) into xib file.
First problem - when I`m trying to change class to CustomHeaderViewClass Xcode
doesn't autocomplete it. I don't know why Xcode can't see this class.

Then, inside ViewController I register headerview:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomHeaderView", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "HeaderIdentifier")
```

And calling method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "HeaderIdentifier") as! CustomHeaderViewClass
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Section: \(section)"
    return cell
}
```

And then my app always crashes with
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x600001314c10> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key centerLabel.'

centerLabel is name of label inside xib file.

Comment: Click on connections-inspector and check if the outlet is connected.

Comment: @RTXGamer everything is connected. I also tried to set object as file`s owner and as custom header view class but result is the same ;(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load XIB this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51056322/load-xib-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key)